# ASP.NET Core Docker build multiple projects fails with 'Program does not contain a static 'Main' method' error

Tags: docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I am getting error when building Docker container for ASP.NET Core web app in VS 2022.

My `Program.cs` looks like this:

```
namespace Catalog.API;

public class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
}
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj", "Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/"]
COPY ["Catalog.Application/Catalog.Application.csproj", "Services/Catalog/Catalog.Application/"]
COPY ["Catalog.Core/Catalog.Core.csproj", "Services/Catalog/Catalog.Core/"]
COPY ["Catalog.Infrastructure/Catalog.Infrastructure.csproj", "Services/Catalog/Catalog.Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API"
RUN dotnet build "Catalog.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Catalog.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Catalog.API.dll"]
```

The Dockerfile is at level of `.sln` file but added in the project `Catalog.API` as an item.

Here is the project in Visual Studio:

[image: Visual Studio solution structure]

Note that `Services` and `Catalog` are solution folders but not real folders:

[image]

I am running the docker build at solution level:

```
docker build -t eshopping-img -f .\Catalog.API\Dockerfile .
```

And getting this error:

```
=> ERROR [build 10/10] RUN dotnet build "Catalog.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build                                   7.2s
------
 > [build 10/10] RUN dotnet build "Catalog.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
0.673 MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
1.262   Determining projects to restore...
2.616   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
5.963   Catalog.Core -> /app/build/Catalog.Core.dll
6.290   Catalog.Application -> /app/build/Catalog.Application.dll
6.610   Catalog.Infrastructure -> /app/build/Catalog.Infrastructure.dll
7.117 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj]
7.133
7.133 Build FAILED.
```

I do have followed many posts also here but I can't find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: How does the `Program.cs` file look?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. I do have Program.cs. I edit my question. Thanks.

Comment: Show us the raw content of your `Catalog.API.csproj` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the output type for the project to **Class Library** instead of **Console Application** in the projects properties. See image below:

[image: Project Properties]

Comment: ASP.NET Core projects need to be Console application project in order to run; it was (pre-Core) ASP.NET-for-.NET-Framework projects that need to be Class Library projects.

Comment: Was not aware of that. Thanks!

Comment: But this is a webapp so why it needs to be set as Console app?

Comment: As @Dai commented above, all .Net Core application projects need to be Console Application projects as default. Then it’s up to you as a developer to choose what kind of application it should be by registering if it should be a MVC web app, razor pages web app, Blazor web app, web api or something else.. in the `program.cs` file.

Comment: Ok and what is the reason for that? THanks because I think I've solved!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it solved! Not sure the reason for it, but my guess is so it can run easily on other platforms like Linux, macOS and Windows. Read more about it here: https://marsner.com/blog/net-core-the-one-platform-for-efficient-cross-os-software-development/